# what is best way to implement jquery ui tab with back/forward button support?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want users to be able to click back/forward button to move between tabs they have click,
but jquery ui's tab don't quite support this yet. Only option that I have found so far is this one, http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/tabs/

is there any simpler or better solution to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution will likely be one that implements hash tags since *most* browsers save hash tags in their history (allowing use of the back and forward buttons).

I recommend making each tab a link with a hash tag and then use [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) to listen for hash change events and then call a function with that event.

For example:

#### HTML snippet:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">This is tab 1!</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">This is tab 2!</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS snippet:

```
#content{
    position:relative;
}
.tab{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}
.tab.active{
    display:block;
}
```

#### JavaScript snippet (using jQuery; assumes document is ready):

```
$(window).hashchange(function(){ //Requires hashchange plugin
    $('#content .tab').removeClass('active'); //Make all tabs inactive
    $(location.hash).addClass('active'); //Activate the tab that has the same ID as the hash
});
```

With some adjustments, this could achieve the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: that jquery address plugin is quite hard to implement, ur idea seems straight forward all i have to do is change url hash value and track change event, hummm... would this work even for nested tabs? i would have to hide/un-hide parent tab as well, will give it a try. thanx

Comment: This could absolutely work for nested tabs, however the implementation would be a little more complex. Maybe you would need to add another class like "active-parent" and when you add the class active to a tab, search for a parent li to that tab and assign the "active-parent" class. (Then adjust the CSS accordingly).

Comment: in the end i ended up using jquery ui tab and this plugin that you suggested.. back button worked even for nested tabs.. thanx a lot! 6 virtual beer pack for u.. lol

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the hash (#) and javascripts native history is that if the user were to click another link outside of the tabs that included a hash then that would break your forward and back buttons.

To get around this try to keep everything inside the jquery ui tabs object, methods and events. Jquery UI Tabs uses an index to specify current tab and to change the tab. Here is the function I use for forward and back buttons:

```
    /**
     * The jquery ui tab forward and back buttons. Remember to replace the
     * '#new-product-tab-container' below with the selector for your tab
     * 
     * @method
     * @public
     * @param {string} dir The direction. Either 'forward' or 'back'
     * @return void
     */
    function tab_nav(dir){

        //vars
        var currentIndex = new Number($('#new-product-tab-container').tabs("option","selected"));
        var newIndex = new Number(0);
        var total = new Number($('#new-product-tab-container .ui-tabs-nav > li').tabs().size());

        if(dir=='forward' && currentIndex < total) newIndex = (currentIndex+1) ;
        if(dir=='back' && currentIndex > 1) newIndex = (currentIndex-1);

        $('#new-product-tab-container').tabs("option","selected", newIndex);

    }
```

The to use this function, call it as `tab_nav('forward')` or `tab_nav('back')`

hope this helps someone ;)

Comment: cool! let's consider another scenario say user copies a url link when she was viewing tab 2, and when she pastes that url at other browser she should be able to view tab2 instead of initial tab1 page. can it be done without adding # at url as well ?

Comment: hey aman. Unfortunately not. The tabs plugin removes the native link abilities in each tab and uses its own onclick event handler.

what you could do to get that functionality is to add some javascript code to the `$(document).ready();` that would parse the url and look for `#tab-content-id` only then would this work

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
$("#tabs").tabs('select', 1);
```

Look at this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/n4mqC/

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all.